# Pentaho kettle add attributes to XML output root element

Tags: xml, etl, pentaho, kettle

I want to generate this output using Kettle XML Output step.
I am able to generate the output but without the attributes in the root  element.
How do I add attributes to the root element? The attribute "Count" and Timestamp values are dynamic and cannot get hard coded.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <Executions ClientCode='xyz" Count=9898 Timestamp=34345454>
   <Trade>
     <Security>MSFT</Security>  
     <Qty>100</Qty>
   </Trade> 
   <Trade>
     <Security>AAPL</Security>  
     <Qty>200</Qty>
   </Trade> 
</Executions>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not able to add attribute values in your parent-xml-element using only "XML Output" step. But you can achieved this using alternate way. I have include a transformation [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PZWaBwHuZnNSpo3OScXV8f7Oomo-5t5z?usp=sharing)

Please let me know if its ok with you.

You can look XMLOutput(1).ktr, where result will be exact your output.